# CSS Leading Ellipsis

Tags: css

Is there anyway to accomplish a leading ellipsis using CSS? Like in a table of contents where the title of the section is followed by ellipsis until the page number which is shown on the right of the page.

Like this:

[image: Ellipsis to end of element.]

(Outlines shown to identify different elements.)

Comment: Given what mark-up? As your question stands you're asking a fairly open question ('not a real question'/'too localized')

Comment: It's okay, just wondering if it is possible...markup doesn't matter much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a crude example with just floated elements/overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/8Ngv5/

It would be less crude if you could fix the widths of all elements.

Here is a more elegant example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Ngv5/2/

This one uses the `:before` pseudo-class to inject a long string which is then covered by the left element. The left element has to be positioned to sit atop the line, and it needs a background to cover the line (see CSS).

This works in IE9, Chrome, and Firefox.

**Result**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">Hello</div>
<div class="right">World</div>
<br>
<div class="left">Another Line</div>
<div class="right">With Longer Content</div>
<br>
<div class="left">Another Line 2</div>
<div class="right">2 With Longer Content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
BODY {
    line-height: 1.2em;    
}

.left {
 float: left; 
 position: relative;
 top: 1.2em;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.right:before {
    content: "...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................";
}

.right {
    float: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Cool, `:before` and `content` are new to me, very interesting!

Comment: Using your suggestion (as well as everyone else's since they're the same), I did this: http://jsfiddle.net/FRBxD/1/ Thanks.

Comment: @JoshM. - nice sample; if you have control over the element width, you can do it even more simply (like you did).

Comment: In this case I wanted the 2nd "column" to all be left justified so setting a width on the first "column" is an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:before` selector and `content: "...";`

```
.some-class:before
{
  content: "...";
}
```

[More examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3abefore)

Answer (score 1):

you could use the :before or :after selectors?